# Total stats on Area 51 commit wrong since the Meta SO/Meta SE split

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51

It looks like the total rep and badges on my Area 51 commitment are being miscalculated. I think it started with the SO/SE meta split.

[image: 31.5k 5,60,158]

Should be:

[image: 19k 4,36,99]

Adding my Meta rep in twice would put my rep in the ballpark of 33k, and the badge counts match exactly if you add in my Meta badges twice.

As of 6/1/2014 problem persists...

As of 8/12/2014 problem persists...

As of 11/30/2014 problem persists...

Comment: The badges, too.

Comment: @michaelb958 thanks, I hadn't even noticed the badges

Comment: This bug makes the [Moderators proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators) look awesome. So much rep!

Comment: As of 11/30/2024 problem persists... (such minor bugs are very rarely getting fixed, hence that's the likely future)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I love the way they don't show comment edits while you're writing comments...

Comment: @ShadowWizard shouldn't it be 11/30/4028 (you have to add the year in twice)

Comment: @apaul34208 comments are minor thing, the team doesn't spend lots of efforts on them on purpose. And yeah, essentially minor bugs usually just wait until they're no longer relevant, e.g. when there won't be global flair anymore.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You would think that a site with an army of programmers/developers at its disposal wouldn't have these ongoing problems... Perhaps there should be a special tag category on SO for fixing SE's bugs.

Comment: US date style makes me twitchy.

Comment: Looks like SE decided to double your Stack Overflow rep. The rest is accurate (like badge count)